# Linux kernel 5.7 - Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, kernel

Does anybody know if/when Linux kernel 5.7 will be officially released for Ubuntu 18.04?

TIA.

Comment: https://www.askmetutorials.com/2020/06/install-linux-kernel-57-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: You can install mainline kernels, as per [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds). However, this is mainly an unsupported testing feature.

Comment: The final HWE kernel for 18.04 is 5.4 (or the kernel used in the next LTS release).  5.8 is the next HWE kernel I believe for 20.04.2 (with HWE enabled), but *groovy* skipped straight from 5.4 to its week+ use of 5.8  (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack)

Answer (score 5):

5.7 won't be released on 18.04. For more recent kernels on an LTS, it is best to opt-into the LTS Enablement Stacks as described in the  [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

For desktop use:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

For server use:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```